# Cause an email to be sent when a file changes on my server

Tags: php, email, http-status-code-404

I have a not_found.php file that takes care of 404 errors. Whenever that file is called by the server, it creates a log file (called 404.txt) in the / directory. The problem I have is I never know when the file (404.txt) is changed so I can fix pages. Example: someone tries to go to mydomain.com/a/logn. The PHP would show as follows:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4roP5r_vEEic2JSOHNaT0hfdTg/edit?usp=sharing

(click the link to see the php file)

Is there any code I can add to tell send an email to me everytime that file is accessed or everytime the 404.txt file is changed?

Answer (score 2):

Add a mail() call in not_found.php, but prepare to be spammed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the php script fire off an email to you

See [PHP - Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)